# undefined method `boarding_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: School, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I having a weird error with ransack. It is returning the error

```
undefined method `boarding_eq' for Ransack::Search<class: School, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

for;

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 pull-left">  
      <%= f.label :boarding_eq, " Boarding Facilities", class: 'search-label ' %>
      <%= f.select :boarding_eq, options_for_select(["","Yes", "No"]), class: 'form-control col-xs-12' %>     
</div>
```

However it works for all the other inputs like;

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6 pull-left">  
     <%= f.label :year_of_establishment_eq, " Boarding Facilities", class: 'search-label ' %>
     <%= f.select :year_of_establishment_eq, options_for_select(["","Yes", "No"]), class: 'form-control col-xs-12' %>     
</div>
```

The school model looks like this;

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :about, :academic_level, :country, :boarding, :district_or_province, 
                  :email_address, :fees, :gender, :information_technology, :number_of_students, 
                  :performing_arts, :phone_number, :photo_1, :photo_2, :photo_3, :photo_4, 
                  :photo_5, :physical_address, :post_address, :school_name, :sports, :town, 
                  :web_address, :year_of_establishment

  validates :about, :academic_level, :country, :boarding, :district_or_province, 
                  :email_address, :gender, :information_technology, :number_of_students, 
                  :performing_arts, :phone_number, :physical_address, :post_address, :school_name,
                  :sports, :town, presence: true

  validates :email, :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, uniqueness:true

  validates :phone_number, uniqueness:true, numericality: true, length: {minimum: 12}             

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :school_events

  has_many :school_reviews

  has_many :votes

  has_one :rating

end
```

and the model migration is as follows;

```
class CreateSchools < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :schools do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :school_name
      t.integer :year_of_establishment
      t.string :number_of_students
      t.string :academic_level
      t.string :phone_number
      t.string :email_address
      t.string :web_address
      t.text :physical_address
      t.integer :post_address
      t.string :country
      t.string :district_or_province
      t.string :town
      t.text :about
      t.string :fees
      t.string :sports
      t.string :information_technology
      t.string :performing_arts
      t.string :gender
      t.string :boarding
      t.text :photo_1
      t.text :photo_2
      t.text :photo_3
      t.text :photo_4
      t.text :photo_5

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :schools, [:user_id, :year_of_establishment]
    add_index :schools, [:school_name, :number_of_students] 
    add_index :schools, [:academic_level, :country ] 
    add_index :schools, [ :district_or_province, :fees ] 
    add_index :schools, [:boarding, :gender ]                      
  end
end
```

I have added the the School Model and the School migration.

Comment: Please show the details of your `School` model.  Also, what type of attribute is `boarding`?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean, i have added them

Comment: Can't think why it doesn't like this field but is fine with all the others.  Does the error appear on building the search or obtaining the results?  Is there anything else useful in the stack trace?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean  obtaining results

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that while i changed the migrations to reflect :boarding, a column with the previous setting had been retained.